# Насколько плохо под каждый страницу сайта делать отдельный HTML файл?

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Новичок, в данный момент занимаюсь версткой и возник вопрос. Не умею реализовывать переключение меню на JS, поэтому приходится под каждую страницу меню делать новый HTML, то есть страницу сайта. Насколько это неправильно? Мне лучше научиться делать это на js?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150532/discussion-on-question-by-xennon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.